# VC++ Trasforming a sample application into a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mfc, exe

I have a project where I received an sample code that is an exe, that basically loads to a dialog two activeX controls.

I need to make an DLL to use the functions of that controls.

What's the best strategy to do this?
I think my DLL need's to make an instance of the window.
and when the window is build get pointers to the activeX controls to make stuff happen.

What is the best strategy to do this? or if it is even possible?

The App Code:
StartUp.h
    #pragma once

```
#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols



// CStartUpApp:
// See StartUp.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CStartUpApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CStartUpApp();

// Overrides
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CStartUpApp theApp;
```

StartUpDlg.h

```
#pragma once
#include "xnssdkdevicectrl.h"
#include "xnssdkwindowctrl.h"


// CStartUpDlg dialog
class CStartUpDlg : public CDialog
{
// Construction
public:
    CStartUpDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);  // standard constructor

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_STARTUP_DIALOG };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support


// Implementation
protected:
    HICON m_hIcon;

    // Generated message map functions
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
    afx_msg void OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

private:
    // [ XNS ACTIVEX HELP ]
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // XNS Device control and Window control variables
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    CXnssdkwindowctrl   m_ctrlXnsWindow;    // XnsWindow control
    CXnssdkdevicectrl   m_ctrlXnsDevice;    // XnsDevice control

public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
};
```

StartUp.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StartUp.h"
#include "StartUpDlg.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CStartUpApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStartUpApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CStartUpApp construction

CStartUpApp::CStartUpApp()
{
    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CStartUpApp object

CStartUpApp theApp;


// CStartUpApp initialization

BOOL CStartUpApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // Standard initialization
    // If you are not using these features and wish to reduce the size
    // of your final executable, you should remove from the following
    // the specific initialization routines you do not need
    // Change the registry key under which our settings are stored
    // TODO: You should modify this string to be something appropriate
    // such as the name of your company or organization
    SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));

    CStartUpDlg dlg;
    m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
    INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
    if (nResponse == IDOK)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with OK
    }
    else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
    {
        // TODO: Place code here to handle when the dialog is
        //  dismissed with Cancel
    }

    // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
    //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
    return FALSE;
}
```

StartUpDlg.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StartUp.h"
#include "StartUpDlg.h"


// [ XNS ACTIVEX HELP ]
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// This files are installed in {$SDK path}\sample_code\include 
// You should include this files
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "XnsCommon.h"
#include "XnsDeviceInterface.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// Macro for OutputDebugString()
#define DBG_LOG(...) do{\
    CString strMessage = _T("");\
    strMessage.AppendFormat(_T("(%S:%d)"), __FUNCTION__, __LINE__); \
    strMessage.AppendFormat(__VA_ARGS__);\
    OutputDebugString(strMessage);\
}while(0);

// Macro for AfxMessageBox()
#define ERROR_BOX(...) do{\
    CString strMessage = _T("");\
    strMessage.Format(__VA_ARGS__);\
    AfxMessageBox(strMessage);\
}while(0);


// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialog
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialog(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CStartUpDlg dialog




CStartUpDlg::CStartUpDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CStartUpDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CStartUpDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_XNSSDKDEVICECTRL, m_ctrlXnsDevice);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_XNSSDKWINDOWCTRL, m_ctrlXnsWindow);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStartUpDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CStartUpDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CStartUpDlg message handlers

BOOL CStartUpDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        CString strAboutMenu;
        strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    // [ XNS ACTIVEX HELP ]
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initializes the DLL files. 
    // For this, XnsActiveX library requires config.xml, device.xml, 
    // and xns.xml files and the DLL file list should be mentioned 
    // in Xns.xml file. The path of the DLL file can not exceed 512 bytes
    // in length. The XnsActiveX library searches for xns.xml using 
    // XnsSDKDevice.ocx installed in "{$SDK path}\Config" folder.
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    long nRet = m_ctrlXnsDevice.Initialize();
    if (nRet != ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DBG_LOG(_T("XnsSdkDevice:: Initialize() fail: errno=[%d]\n"), nRet);
    }

    // [ XNS ACTIVEX HELP ]
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initializes the XnsSdkWindow control. 
    // Namely, this will specify the window handle in order to display 
    // images on the screen. 
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    nRet = m_ctrlXnsWindow.Initialize(NULL, NULL);
    DBG_LOG(_T("XnsSdkWindow:: Initialize() return=[%d](%s)\n"), 
        nRet, m_ctrlXnsDevice.GetErrorString(nRet));


    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CStartUpDlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CStartUpDlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialog::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CStartUpDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


void CStartUpDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    OnOK();
}
```

my dll header

```
__declspec(dllexport) long init();//initilize app with activeX controls in window
__declspec(dllexport) long getDlgInstance();//get dlg handle to be able to call activeX
__declspec(dllexport) long connect(long handle);//do stuff
```

Comment: @Elemental I don't understand your question?

Comment: if you need to launch a dialog and return a pointer to the dialog, it needs to be a modeless dialog and your calling program will need to close the dialog properly before it exits -- is this what you want? or should it be a modal dialog box and the init function not return until the dialog box is closed?

Comment: it's going to be controlled by the dll, so it's the modeless dialog option that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be that hard...
Without having seen your code (how could I?), I assume you defined functions to return the pointers of the activeX controls to the caller.
Judging by the questions you asked earlier you know how to make a DLL. Get all the code you need in a new DLL project, export only the functions you want to access from the host application and you're done

Comment: added the app code.
my main problem let's say I have a init function on my dll that will initiate the window, launch the activex controls and return an handle to the Cdialog, how do I do that?

Comment: Exactly like you said. Let your function return the handle you want. If you want to also get a reference/pointer to the activex controls, you can add  additional (out-)parameters to that function.

you also might want to declare a macro to handle the `__declspec(import)` and `__declspec(export)` for you. This is also explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9xyb5w93%28v=VS.120%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your DLL code would look something like

```
__declspec (dllexport) CStartUpDlg *ShowStartUpDlg()
{   AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()); // in case the dialog is in the DLL's .rc file
    // alternate to the above line: AfxSetResourceHandle(hInstance); // hInstance is what you get in the DLL's InitInstance()

    CStartUpDlg *pDlg = new CStartUpDlg();
    if (pDlg == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (!pDlg->Create(IDD_STARTUP_DLG))
        return NULL;
    pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    return pDlg; // make sure you close the dialog and delete pDlg at the end of your program
}
```